# How does 100% - 40 wοrk in Java?

Tags: java, operators, modulo, unary-operator

```java
System.out.println(100% - 40);
```

Please explain the steps the compiler takes to resolve this.

Like I understand % is an operator which takes two operands to work but how is it accepting another operator like "-" minus in this case?

Comment: 100 modulo (minus 40). You have just formatted it strangely. I would write it as `100 % -40`

Comment: 10 modulo 1000 = 10, since it divides zero times, and the remainder is 10.

Comment: `10 % (+1000) = 10 % 1000 = 10` read about operators precedence.

Comment: "100% + 40" is a strangely formatted "100 % +40", which is the same as "100 % 40"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formatting here is important to read it properly.

```
System.out.println(100 % -40);
```

or

```
System.out.println(100 % (-40));
```

Then, it becomes clear that there are two operators: the remainder operator `%` and the unary minus operator `-`.

Furthermore, [the operator precedence table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) explains why this terribly unusual expression works even without round brackets.

```
┌────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│   Operators    │          Precedence ↓         │
├────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ unary          │ ++expr --expr +expr -expr ~ ! │
│ multiplicative │ * / %                         │
└────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not be read the way it is written.

% here does not represent percentage. Instead, it represent modulus.

Therefore the answer would be 100 mod (minus 40) i.e. 100%(-40)

I hope this helps you out